# Changing styles onPress event React Native

Tags: react-native, styles

I've a problem with changing styles using onPress event, originally i've width = 75 and height too ([default values of width and height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFmJ1.png)), but When I use onPress  I want to trigger the method ([method What I would like to use for replace styles value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya6u1.png))  which will replace value of **width** and **height** to **65**. Can you tell me any solution for solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a touchableHighlight with is imported from 'react-native'
Your constructor should hold a varaible for the press status:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    pressStatus: false 
  };
}
```

The two function that handles when the touchableHighlight is pressed.

```
_onHideUnderlay(){
  this.setState({ pressStatus: false });
}
_onShowUnderlay(){
  this.setState({ pressStatus: true });
}
```

The touchable could look like

```
<TouchableHighlight
        onPress={()=>{}}
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        style={this.state.pressStatus ? styles.buttonPress : styles.button}
        onHideUnderlay={this._onHideUnderlay.bind(this)}
        onShowUnderlay={this._onShowUnderlay.bind(this)}
        >
  <Text>Press</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Then add to the styleSheet

```
button: {
    alignSelf:'center',
    borderColor: '#000066',
    backgroundColor: '#000066',
    width:65,
    height:65
  },
  buttonPress: {
    alignSelf:'center',
    borderColor: '#000066',
    backgroundColor: '#000066',
    width:75,
    height:75
  },
```

Comment: Yeah! It works for me!Thank you Simon for your help!)

Comment: No worries! Happy to be able to pass some of my knowledge forward.

Answer (score 2):

You can change a state variable from `75` to `65` in your `onPress` method and use that variable to overwrite your width/height.

`<YourElement style={[styles.yourOriginalStylesheet, {width: this.state.size, height: this.state.size}]}>`

Alternatively, you could define another style object and conditionally apply it based on a boolean state variable that you change in `onPress`.

`<YourElement style={[styles.yourOriginalStylesheet, this.state.changeSize && styles.yourStylesheetWithNewSizes]}>`

Answer (score 0):

Im on my cell so this becomes kind of a pseudo code that I could not verify.

One way to sole it is to create a function that is called onPress. This function changes the state variable. 
In the styling you look if the state variable is true ir false.

Function
handlePress(){this.setState({pressed:true})}

in your button/view or what you want to style
onPress={()=>handlePress()}

In your styling

width:this.state.pressed?75:65

If pressed is true it will gice the first value after the questionmark otherwise the second value.

Comment: this moment **width:this.state.pressed?75:65** response error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.pressed')

Comment: You should add pressed:false in the state props in the constructor also.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html  copy the enture constricor from the link and add pressed:false

Comment: it's okay. Work well. The function is called when I pressed the button but I need the method to be called when I only touch the button that is when I pressed and do not release the button

Comment: I think I need to use addEventListener with 'mousedown' type

Comment: I added a new answer about touchableHighlight instead. Might be of use instead of adding eventListeners.